# How p/invoke call function using only but C++ need the .a/.lib/.o files?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, mingw, pinvoke

How is even possible to .NET's P/invoke call a function within a DLL using only the dll file but for C++ you can't do it without the `.a/.lib`/`.o` files?

Background:

I'm trying to use a function from a dll "written" in C++ from a C++/CLI application but I've told that only the dll file plus header isn't enough I need to the `.a/.lib`/`.o` files too. How this dll was compiled using minGw and C++/CLI doesn't support `.a` files but only `.lib`s I'll have to recompile this dll using MSVC compiler/linker. So I wonder why does this "simple" thing in C# works:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        EntryPoint="_Z9getNumberv")]
    public static extern int GetNumber();
```

But a dll in and for C++ it take more work/need to files.  I'm a begginer so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: You don't *need* an import library for static linking.

Comment: @Cheersandhth yup, I was thinking about the `.def` file actually.

Comment: You can simply create the import .lib file and you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `GetProcAddress` in C++ and invoke directly with that. That's similar to what P/Invoke does.

The use of an import library is to enable the standard linker to work (whereas P/Invoke and `GetProcAddress` bypass the linker).

Comment: With both MS and GNU tools an import library is technically unnecessary. It's just a convenience. But the OP has a point in that the C++ *language* does not support dynamic libraries: with C++ it's a tool issue, only.